"BigLake managed tables are not supported."
trying to run following command from the data-analytics-golden-demo repository (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/data-analytics-golden-demo/blob/main/sql-scripts/taxi_dataset...) and this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D4BhIraXP-I) to create a BigLake Managed Table (I of course put proper values and all, just for simplicity I copy pasted from the repository):
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `${project_id}.biglake_managed_tables.iceberg_mt_random_name`
(
string_field_0 STRING
)
CLUSTER BY string_field_0
WITH CONNECTION `${project_id}.us.biglake-connection`
OPTIONS (
file_format = 'PARQUET',
table_format = 'ICEBERG',
storage_uri = 'gs://${biglake_managed_tables_bucket_name}/biglake-managed-tables/iceberg_mt_random_name');

Unfortunately I'm being met with following error and can't find any documentation about that:

I've tried it on multi-regions (dataset and external connector) US and EU, tried it on specific regions (us-central1, europe-west1) and I'm getting the same message everytime.
Any advice?

I believe BigLake Managed Tables are not yet fully available.  Likely they are unlocked by talking to Google and enrolling in the preview.  I wasn't able to find a reference to Managed Tables in the documentation.  Have you found such documentation?

I haven't found anything related to Managed tables except from the Videos and Repository, so your point does make sense. Thanks!
